# How to match repeated characters using regular expression operator =~ in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to know if a string has repeated letter 6 times or more, using the =~ operator.

```
a="aaaaaaazxc2"
if [[ $a =~ ([a-z])\1{5,} ]];
then
     echo "repeated characters"
fi
```

The code above does not work.

Comment: So you want `\1` to be a backreference? That's a PCRE extension, not available in POSIX ERE.

Comment: Yes, if I use `egrep '([a-z])\1{5,}' file`, it works.

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions, or http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html for the formal spec. The capability you want simply isn't available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BASH regex flavor i.e. **ERE** doesn't support backreference in regex. [`ksh93` and `zsh` support it though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361139/5839).

As an alternate solution, you can do it using *extended regex* option in `grep`:

```
a="aaaaaaazxc2"
grep -qE '([a-zA-Z])\1{5}' <<< "$a" && echo "repeated characters"

repeated characters
```

---

**EDIT:** Some ERE implementations support backreference as an extension. For example `Ubuntu 14.04` supports it. See snippet below:

```
$> echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.11(1)-release

$> a="aaaaaaazxc2"
$> re='([a-z])\1{5}'
$> [[ $a =~ $re ]] && echo "repeated characters"
repeated characters
```

Comment: I found out that backreference is supported in Ubuntu.

Comment: Rather, on Ubuntu's libc. Meaning you're not dependent even on the specific build of bash (working anywhere the same version is compiled with the same options), but *the platform it's running on*. That's about as nonportable as things get.

Answer (score 2):

`[[ $var =~ $regex ]]` parses a regular expression in POSIX ERE syntax.

See [the POSIX regex standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), emphasis added:

> `BACKREF` - **Applicable only to basic regular expressions**. The character string consisting of a  character followed by a single-digit numeral, '1' to '9'.

Backreferences are not formally specified by the POSIX standard for ERE; thus, they are not guaranteed to be available (subject to platform-specific libc extensions) in bash's native regex syntax, thus mandating the use of external tools (awk, grep, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the full power of backreferences for this specific case of one character repeats. You could just build the regex that would check for a repeat of every single lower case letter

```
regex="a{6}"
for x in {b..z} ; do regex="$regex|$x{6}" ; done    
if [[ "$a" =~ ($regex) ]] ; then echo "repeated characters" ; fi
```

The regex built with the above for loop looks like

```
> echo "$regex" | fold -w60
a{6}|b{6}|c{6}|d{6}|e{6}|f{6}|g{6}|h{6}|i{6}|j{6}|k{6}|l{6}|
m{6}|n{6}|o{6}|p{6}|q{6}|r{6}|s{6}|t{6}|u{6}|v{6}|w{6}|x{6}|
y{6}|z{6}
```

This regular expression behaves as you would expect

```
> if [[ "abcdefghijkl" =~ ($regex) ]] ; then \
  echo "repeated characters" ; else echo "no repeat detected" ; fi
no repeat detected
> if [[ "aabbbbbbbbbcc" =~ ($regex) ]] ; then \
  echo "repeated characters" ; else echo "no repeat detected" ; fi
repeated characters
```

**Updated** following the comment from @sln replaced bound `{6,}` expression with a simple `{6}`.

Comment: You don't need the  _more_ part, just a `{6}` because matching more than 6 doesn't give you information.